# How to calulate Euclidean distance? (HSL)

Tags: javascript, html, swift, image, colors

Because I read an article that the [HSL color scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is pretty accurate to the humans eye color scheme I'm pretty sure **HSL comparison** is the best method to check if two colors are similar.

---

**Starting with this:**

I got two HSL colors like...

- one reference color: `296° 100% 62%` (as `[296, 100, 62]`)
- one other color: `290° 100% 40%` (as `[290, 100, 40]`)

... and I'd like to calculate a percentage that symbolizes their similarity.

So these two colors (`[296, 100, 62]` and `[290, 100, 40]`) are looking pretty similar while `[296, 100, 62]` & `[196, 30, 32]` does not.

How to calculate the **Euclidean distance** to get a value for their difference?

```
var color1 = [296, 100, 62]
var hue1 = color1[0],      // hue          (values: 0-360)
    sat1 = color1[1],      // saturation   (values: 0-100)
    lig1 = color1[2]       // light        (values: 0-100)

var color2 = [290, 100, 40]
var hue2 = color2[0],      // hue          (values: 0-360)
    sat2 = color2[1],      // saturation   (values: 0-100)
    lig2 = color2[2]       // light        (values: 0-100)


?? How to calculate there difference?
```

**Note**: Here you can have a look at the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry)

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distance measure between HSL colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231410/distance-measure-between-hsl-colours)

Comment: This is no duplicate of the question you linked! @v.karbovnichy I'm trying to calculate the Euclidean distance while in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231410/distance-measure-between-hsl-colours the OP not!

Comment: mm you asked generic question about the difference, and the Euclidian distance is just one of the possible ways. So answering your question `How to calculate a value for their difference?` is that link.

Comment: make sure you are not trapped by [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) with Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean distance in a cylinder... is not really possible.

You should check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference in Wikipedia. You will see that euclidean distance could be done with RGB (each value of triplet can go to infinity). But such distance is not so precise.

On the above page, you will see that in 1994 and in 2000 CIE improved the method to calculate color differences, in a Euclidean like way, but using LCh color model, which is nor much different to HSL (chroma vs saturation). The 2000 version has some correcting factors.

In any case, color differences are valid only when dE is less then 6. Above such limit, you cannot compare dE. So it is ok to say a color is similar (or not) to an other, but you cannot compare very different colors (vs a reference) if dE is large.